# Why would a variable be evaluated to nil in an rspec spec when it contains a value?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I don't understand this at all:

In a nutshell, this

```
it "should assign @user_friendship_1 to the instance variable #|@user_friendships|" do
    var = "something"
    ap @user_friendship_1
    var.should == @user_friendship_1
end
```

results in this bizarre error:

```
.#<UserFriendship:0x000001031fb6f8> {
            :id => 1,
     :friend_id => 2,
       :user_id => 1,
    :created_at => Tue, 10 Dec 2013 05:56:54 UTC +00:00,
    :updated_at => Tue, 10 Dec 2013 05:56:54 UTC +00:00,
         :state => "accepted"
}
....

Failures:

  1) UserFriendshipsController: When four valid User instances exist, @user_1, @user_2, @user_3, @user_4, and when logged in as @user_, and when a UserFriendship, @user_friendship_1, is joining @user_1 with @user_2, a PATCH request to the #edit action with the :id of @user_friendship_1 should assign @user_friendship_1 to the instance variable #|@user_friendship_1|
     Failure/Error: assigns(:dfsdf).should == @user_frienship_1
       expected: nil
            got: "something" (using ==)
```

I mean WHAT? `ap` proves that @user_friendship_1 is a hash, and exactly the same variable is evaluated at `nil` when inside the expectation? What on earth?

spec:

```
require 'spec_helper'
require 'ap'

describe UserFriendshipsController do


   context "\b: When four valid User instances exist, @user_1, @user_2, @user_3, @user_4" do
        before do
            @user_1 = FactoryGirl.create(:user_with_all_valid)
            @user_1.reload

            @user_2 = FactoryGirl.create(:user_with_all_valid_two)
            @user_2.reload

            @user_3 = FactoryGirl.create(:user_with_all_valid_three)
            @user_3.reload

            @user_4 = FactoryGirl.create(:user_with_all_valid_four)
            @user_4.reload
        end

        context "\b, and when not logged in" do
            before do
            end

            context "\b, a PUT request to the #accept action" do
                before do
                    put :accept, id: 1
                end

                it "should redirect to the login page" do
                    response.response_code.should == 302
                    response.should be_redirect
                    response.should redirect_to new_user_session_path
                end
            end 
        end

        context "\b, and when logged in as @user_1" do
            before do
                sign_in @user_1
            end

            context "\b, and when a UserFriendship, @user_friendship_1, is joining @user_1 with @user_2" do
                before do
                    @user_friendship_1 = FactoryGirl.create(:pending_user_friendship, user_id: @user_1.id, friend_id: @user_2.id)
                    @user_friendship_1.reload
                end

                it "@user_friendship_1.state should equal 'pending' by default, when it is created" do
                    @user_friendship_1.state.should == 'pending'
                end

                context "\b, a PATCH request to the #edit action with the :id of @user_friendship_1" do
                    before do
                        patch :edit, id: @user_friendship_1.id
                        @user_friendship_1.reload
                    end

                    it "should assign @user_friendship_1 to the instance variable #|@user_friendship_1|" do
                        puts "****"
                        ap @user_frienship_1
                    end
                    it "should assign @user_friendship_1 to the instance variable #|@user_friendship_1|" do
                        assigns(:dfsdf).should == @user_frienship_1
                    end
                    it "should assign @user_friendship_1 to the instance variable #|@user_friendship_1|" do

                        puts @user_friendships_1.inspect

                        assigns(:dfsdf).should_not == @user_frienship_1

                    end
                end

                context "\b, a PUT request to the #accept action with the :id of @user_friendship_1" do
                    before do
                        put :accept, id: @user_friendship_1.id
                        @user_friendship_1.reload
                    end

                    it "should assign @user_friendship_1 to the instance variable #|@user_friendships|" do
                        var = "something"

                        ap @user_friendship_1
                        var.should == @user_friendship_1
                    end


                    it "should change @user_friendship_1.state from 'pending' to 'accepted' " do
                        @user_friendship_1.state.should == 'accepted'   
                    end

                    it "should populate the flash[:success] with the success message '' " do
                        flash[:success].should == "You are now friends with " + @user_2.first_name + "!"
                    end

                    it "should redirect to the show route of that friendship" do
                        response.should redirect_to user_friendship_path 
                    end
                end 
            end
      end
  end
```

factories:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
    factory :status_one, class: Status do
    #   name "Here is numerano Uno Status!"
        content "This is definitely the number one status! One, as in 1!"
    end

    factory :user_with_all_valid, class: User do
        first_name "jimmy"
        last_name "Thehat"
        profile_name "Jimbohatboy"  
        sequence (:email){ |n| "awesomedog" + n.to_s + "@hotmail.co.uk" }
        password "thisisasupersecretpassword12234234"
        password_confirmation "thisisasupersecretpassword12234234"
    end

    # look into the following:
    # we can nest factories
    # we can use sequences to increment email addresses and make them unique
    # we can set up associations (below)

    # use fresh users here, that's what'ss causing the error

    factory :user_friendship_1, class: UserFriendship do
        association :user, factory: :user_with_all_valid_five
        # or :user_id, factory: :user_with_all_valid[id]
        association :friend, factory: :user_with_all_valid_six
        # or :friend_id, factory: :user_with_all_valid_two[id]

        factory :pending_user_friendship do
            state 'pending'
        end

        factory :requested_user_friendship do
            state 'requested'
        end

        factory :accepted_user_friendship do
            state 'accepted'
        end
    end

    factory :user_with_all_valid_two, class: User do
        first_name "Mattychips"
        last_name "Matthews"
        profile_name "Chipboy76"    
        email "Chips@hotmail.co.uk"
        password "yeahyeahsupersecret"
        password_confirmation "yeahyeahsupersecret"
    end

    factory :user_with_all_valid_three, class: User do
        first_name "Ratty"
        last_name "Excellent"
        profile_name "Ratexcellent" 
        email "rat@hotmail.co.uk"
        password "hello_987"
        password_confirmation "hello_987"
    end

    factory :user_with_all_valid_four, class: User do
        first_name "Sylvia"
        last_name "Plath"
        profile_name "collosus64676421" 
        email "collosus@987987.co.uk"
        password "thisisasupersecretpassword12234234"
        password_confirmation "thisisasupersecretpassword12234234"
    end 
end
```

model:

```
class UserFriendship < ActiveRecord::Base
    # sets the 'state' column to pending whenever a new model (UserFriendship) is created
    state_machine :state, initial: :pending do

        after_transition on: :accept, do: :send_accept_email
=begin 
    this creates an action called 'accepted!' and changes the 'state' column to 'accepted' when called
    it's basically a shorthand for this method (the exclamation mark, nothing more than a practise that doesn't
    change the code) is automatically added to the method name. This is because it's a potentially
    dangerous bang method that we've made:

    event :accept do
        transition any => :accepted
    end 

    is the same as writing:

    def accept!
        self.state == 'accepted'
    end

=end
        event :accept do
            transition any => :accepted
        end

        state :requested


    end


    belongs_to :user

=begin this right here, is where the friend model comes into existance.

    belongs_to :friend, class_name: 'User'

    is basically a shorthand for creating a new model file, friend.rb and populating it with the same
    contents as user.rb (I think..maybe just the attributes and certain associations)
=end
    belongs_to :friend, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'friend_id'
```

controller:

```
class UserFriendshipsController < ApplicationController
    before_filter :authenticate_user!, only: [:new, :create, :index, :accept]

    def accept
        # why does this need to be scoped to the current user? This does the same thing:
        #   
        # @user_friendships = UserFriendship.find_by_id(params[:id])
        #
        # exactly the same result. Find out the benefit and the reasoning.

        @user_friendships = current_user.user_friendships.find_by_id(params[:id])

        # a shorthand for if @user_friendships.accept! == true . All methods evaluate to boolean true
        # 'true' if they are successful, and false if otherwise. This way, we can do a simple statement:
        if @user_friendships.accept!
            flash[:success] = "You are now friends with " + @user_friendships.friend.first_name + "!"
        else
            flash[:error] = "Friendship between you, " + current_user.profile_name + " and " + @user_friendships.friend.first_name + "could not be created"
        end

        redirect_to user_friendship_path
    end

    def edit
        @dfsdf = "cheese"       
    end

    def index
        @user_friendships = current_user.user_friendships.load
    end

    def new 
        if params[:friend_id]

            @friend = User.find_by_profile_name(params[:friend_id])
            @user_friendship = current_user.user_friendships.new(friend: @friend)

        else
            flash[:error] = "Friend required"
        end

        if @friend

        else
            flash[:notice] = "That user could not be found"
            render file: 'public/404', status: 404
        end 
=begin

        rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
            flash[:notice] = "That user could not be found"
            render file: 'public/404', status: 404
=end            


    end

    def create

        if params[:user_friendship][:friend_id]

            @friend = User.find_by_id(params[:user_friendship][:friend_id])
            logger.fatal @friend.inspect
        else

        end

        if @friend

            current_user.user_friendships.create(friend: @friend)

            flash[:success] = @friend.profile_name + " added as friend!"
            redirect_to profile_path(@friend.profile_name), status: 302

        else
            flash[:error] = "Friend required!"
            redirect_to root_path, status: 302
        end 
    end

end
```

spec_helper:

```
# This file is copied to spec/ when you run 'rails generate rspec:install'
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'capybara/rspec'
require 'ap'

def set(factory)
  @user = FactoryGirl.create(factory) 
end


# Requires supporting ruby files with custom matchers and macros, etc,
# in spec/support/ and its subdirectories.
Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each { |f| require f }

# Checks for pending migrations before tests are run.
# If you are not using ActiveRecord, you can remove this line.
ActiveRecord::Migration.check_pending! if defined?(ActiveRecord::Migration)

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Capybara::DSL
=begin
  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end

  config.after(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end

  config.after(:suite) do
#   DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
#   DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end
=end

  # Remove this line if you're not using ActiveRecord or ActiveRecord fixtures
  # config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"

  # config.include RSpec::Rails::RequestExampleGroup, type: :feature

  # If you're not using ActiveRecord, or you'd prefer not to run each of your
  # examples within a transaction, remove the following line or assign false
  # instead of true.
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true

  # If true, the base class of anonymous controllers will be inferred
  # automatically. This will be the default behavior in future versions of
  # rspec-rails.
  config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = false

  # Run specs in random order to surface order dependencies. If you find an
  # order dependency and want to debug it, you can fix the order by providing
  # the seed, which is printed after each run.
  #     --seed 1234
  config.order = "random"
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters, the example you cited initially is not the example that failed. The sample that failed is in the "PATCH" context based on the description chain that is output in the failure message. But none of the `it` blocks in that context assign `"something"` to `var` or output `var`.

And, thanks to the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20488203/1008891), you can see that you have a `@user_frienship-1` typo in the example that is failing:

```
it "should assign @user_friendship_1 to the instance variable #|@user_friendship_1|" do
  assigns(:dfsdf).should == @user_frienship_1
end
```

Since undefined instance variables evaluate to `nil`, you're getting the failure in question.

As an aside, this is an example of why it's a good idea to avoid using `before` to assign instance variables in your RSpec tests in favor of using `let` to assign regular variables, as invalid references to regular variables will generate an error rather than silently returning `nil`.

Answer (score 0):

You've typoed `@user_friendship_1` as `@user_frienship_1` quite a few times in those specs. I suspect it may be relevant.